# How to manipulate Navigation Controller?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

I'm just starting to learn xcode and wondered, how do I reverse the flow of **Navigation Controller**? I have 1 `TableViewController` and 1 `ViewController`, and I want the `ViewController` to appear first. Please help.

Instead of:

```
NavigationController >>> TableViewController >>> ViewController
```

I want it like this:

```
NavigationController >>> ViewController >>> TableViewController and back to ViewController
```

Comment: You can make `TableViewController` to be a child of your `ViewController`, and I guess that would solve your problem if I get your problem right

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! Anyway, how about passing data from ViewController's UITextField to TableViewController's static cells?

Comment: I guess you would be able to do it by let your `ViewController` read that data and then pass it to `UITableViewController` and that hand it over to the static cell.

Comment: Okay then, I have to make another class aside from the defaults, right?

Comment: That can be done by using Delegate pattern. Define a delegate and have your static cell implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If your view hierarchy in storyboard is as:
a:UITableViewController(A) embedded with UINavigationController.
b:Now UIViewController(B) is comming from UITableViewController(A).

1. You can change the order of A and B as embeed UINavigationController from B instead of embedding it from A and now call A from B ie. Take UIViewController, then embeed UINavigationController in it and now add UITableViewController to be pushed from UIViewConrtroller.

Comment: Actually, when running the program, it must start in `UIViewController` first, and the sequence must be:
`UINavigationController` >>> `UITableViewController` >>> `UIViewController`

Comment: for this you can push the controller from UITableViewController to UIViewController in ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear.

Comment: Oh thanks! I will also try that. Our instructor told us to find different ways since we're the pioneers of our school. Just a quick question, is it different from `Unwind Segues`?

Comment: Yes we do this programatically rather than using segues of storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To show the UITableViewController instance and skip UIViewController instance:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[myViewController, myTableViewController] animated:YES];
```

To pop to UIViewController instance and skip UITableViewController instance:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[myViewController] animated:YES];
```